# Getting three exactly different results when using buffer analysis tool in similar ways

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, buffer

Three-times inputs are showed on pictures.

Buffer of **Export_Output_2_Buffer2 (green one)** is exactly what I'm looking forward (undissolved buffers)to get.
So I'm wondering why does it happen, and if I want to get undissolved buffers directly (rather than have such three tries), what shall I do?

[image: confused]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: The answer is in the question.... Use meters instead of miles, and don't disolve the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not enter the same parameters each time you ran your buffer.

In your Green result (the one you say is what you want) you entered the following:

- Distance `500 Meters`
- Side Type `FULL`
- End Type `ROUND`
- Dissolve Type `NONE`

In your Brown result you entered the following:

- **Distance `300 Meters`**
- Side Type `FULL`
- End Type `ROUND`
- **Dissolve Type `ALL`**

In your Yellow result you entered the following:

- **Distance `300 Miles`**
- Side Type `FULL`
- End Type `ROUND`
- Dissolve Type `None`

So in order to replicate what you want (the green buffer) you need to set your Distance to `500 Meters` (not `300 Meters` or `300 Miles`) and your Dissolve Type to `NONE` (not `ALL`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my carelessness.